# How to use Ngrx navigation function?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I came across [navigation](https://ngrx.io/api/router-store/data-persistence/navigation) from NgRx. After reading the documentation my understanding is this `effect` will be triggered when the component is loaded. But unfortunately this effect is not getting triggered. I have tested with other `effects` & they are triggering as expected

```
export class RouterEffects {

  private actions$ = inject(Actions);
  private routerFacade: RouterFacade = inject(RouterFacade);
  private shellFacade: ShellFacade = inject(ShellFacade);
  private appService: AppService = inject(AppService);
  private router = inject(Router);

  getProfile$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      navigation(LoginComponent, {
        run: (a: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, ...slices): Observable < Action > | Action | void => {
          console.log('hello')
          return this.appService.getProfile()
            .pipe(map((profile) => ({
              type: 'Load',
              todo: profile
            })))
        },
        onError: (a: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, e: any) => {
          console.log(e)
          return null
        }
      })
    ));
}
```

The effect is also added to the standalone application config

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptors([httpInterceptor])),
    provideRouter(appRoutes),
    provideStore({
      router: routerReducer
    }),
    provideState({
      name: SHELL_FEATURE_KEY,
      reducer: shellReducer
    }),
    provideEffects([ShellEffects, RouterEffects]),
    provideRouterStore({
      //serializer:RouteSerializer
    }),
    provideStoreDevtools({
      // dev tool config
    })
  ],
};
```

My question is what I am doing wrong and how I can make `navigation` function work

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the answer

We need to add [FullRouterStateSerializer](https://ngrx.io/api/router-store/FullRouterStateSerializer) class in `provideRouterStore` serializer

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptors([httpInterceptor])),
    provideRouter(appRoutes),
    provideStore({
      router: routerReducer
    }),
    provideState({
      name: SHELL_FEATURE_KEY,
      reducer: shellReducer
    }),
    provideEffects([ShellEffects, RouterEffects]),
    provideRouterStore({
      serializer: FullRouterStateSerializer

    }),
    provideStoreDevtools({
      // dev tool config
    })
  ],
};
```